# Cannot enable JTextField on button click

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I am not sure why my JTextField is not being enabled when it is clicked.

Here is the code where I create and set the JTextField:

```
PromptHandler ph = new PromptHandler(this);
textPanel = new JPanel();
arEntry = new JTextField(REGION_TEXT_FIELD_COLUMNS);
arEntry.setToolTipText(ENTER_NEW_REGION_ID_TITLE_TEXT);
arEntry.setActionCommand(ENTER_NEW_REGION_ID_TITLE_TEXT);
arEntry.addActionListener(ph);
textPanel.add(arEntry);
```

And here is the code in PromptHandler that takes care of the text field:

```
private HelloWorld hwApp;
private String id;

public PromptHandler (HelloWorld hw) {
    hwApp = hw;
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
    String command = ae.getActionCommand();
    switch(command) {
        case ENTER_NEW_REGION_ID_TITLE_TEXT:
            hwApp.arEntry.setEnabled(true);
            break;
```

Comment: If you have previously invoked `arEntry.setEnabled(false)`, how can `actionPerformed()` ever be called?

Comment: How are you monitoring the field for mouse events??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ActionListener` has nothing to with mouse interaction.  `ActionListener`s are used to provide notification of some nondescript action that can occur with a component.  In the case of the `JTextField`, it normally means that the user has triggered some "apply" action (typically via the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key)

If you want to monitor a fields interaction with the mouse, then you need a `MouseListener`

```
public class TestField {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestField();
    }

    public TestField() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            JTextField field = new JTextField(20);
            field.setEnabled(false);
            add(field);
            field.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                    e.getComponent().setEnabled(!e.getComponent().isEnabled());
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

My concern with this is, why?  If you're going to enable the field on click that what's the point of disabling it?  The only thing that will do is prevent it from receiving key board focus until it is enabled.

Comment: The thing is that the text field is not enabled. Key events don't work either.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking to disable or enable your JTextField?

I'm pretty sure when you create a JTextField object, it is already enabled unless you disable it after creating it. So your action listener is doing nothing in terms of changing the state of the JTextField.

Comment: The text field is never setEnabled(false), so I wasn't sure why it wasn't already clickable. That's why I added the case in the actionPerformed method, as I figured on a click the text field could be enabled. PromptHandler implements ActionListener, do I need to implement another interface?

Comment: Could you post the whole code where you created the JTextField itself including the variables?